# Vuetify 2: How to adjust the v-navigation-drawer to not to change the position of the v-content

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I think trying to describe it can get confusing, so from the images, I think the problem is going to be much clearer...

[Follow the link my Codepen](https://codepen.io/magnoalberto/pen/JjdRKqE?editors=1011)

If I use `app` in `v-navigation-drawer`, it comes close to what I would like, but I don't want `v-navigation-drawer` to occupy the entire side, overlapping the main bar (`v-app-bar`). What I would like you to occupy only the side, but "without" overlapping the main bar (`v-app-bar`), but mostly, don't "throw" the `v-content` to the bottom of the screen

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer">
```

[image]

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `<header>` tag around `<v-navigation-drawer>` and simply override vuetify css using `!important`

here is a working example: [Live Demo](https://codepen.io/hamedbaatour/pen/gOpwwjJ)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, this helps a lot, but in your example, the navbar "drags" the main content (container) to the side, what I needed would be for the navbar overlapping the main content (container)

Comment: oh, gotcha! then simply remove the `v-content` tag and vuetify will stop adding padding that pushes the content the left. I have updated the live demo with a fix!

Comment: please mark the answer as a solution (by clicking on the checkmark)

Comment: Only to share for those who need it, using the `v-content > v-container fluid` it is perfect